# Generating a question mark within the SSRS subscription

Tags: reporting-services

I am having a problem with one of the SSRS Subscription. One of the users, reported to me that questions mark generated before to email address, hence making the email addresses invalid. I checked the subscription itself and there were no question marks.

Do you know what could cause the question marks?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having this problem. I have written what culd have been the problem and what I did to resolve. The problem occured because of spaces between the semi colon and the email addresses. Hence, I removed the spaces and I also re-added the email addresses. This seem to have worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything that would cause question marks to appear in the users e-mail address in a subscription. Are your e-mail addresses generated from a query in Data Driven subscription? That would seem to be the only way and the field would still need to have a question mark in it.

This claim seems dubious - if the user wasn't able to get the e-mail, how do they know that it is because of a question mark? Is there an error in the subscription Status column?

Try adding yourself to the subscription and change the schedule to send one out while you watch to check to see if it's delivered.

Comment: Noo, its just a normal subscription. The user complained that in the list of the email addresss. There was a question mark next to two user email addresses.  The subscription seems to be okay.

Comment: I still don't understand where they were seeing the question mark. If it's not data-driven, it should go to the address you see in the TO field.
Have you tried changing the TO address to your email and test to see if the subscription works for you?
Are you using the full email display name - John Smith <john.smith@example.org>? Maybe there a ? in there?

Comment: Hello, I think the spaces were causing the problem. I removed the spaces between the semicolon and the email address. I also removed and re added the email addresses. It worked fine. Thank you for your effort.